# Arithmetic operation on all elements in BASH array

Tags: arrays, bash, arithmetic-expressions

Say we have a BASH array with integers:

```
declare -a arr=( 1 2 3 )
```

and I want to do an arithmetic operation on each element, e.g. add 1. Is there an altenative to a for loop:

```
for (( i=0 ; i<=${#arr[@]}-1 ; i++ )) ; do
    arr[$i]=$(( ${arr[$i]} + 1 ))
done
```

I have tried a few options:

```
arr=$(( ${arr[@]} + 1 ))
```

fails, while

```
arr=$(( $arr + 1 ))
```

results in

```
echo ${arr[@]}
2 2 3
```

thus only the first (zeroth) element being changed.

I read about `awk` solutions, but would like to know if BASH arithmetics support such batch operations on each array element.

Comment: I don't think there is an alternative. As a side note, none of the programming languages I use can do that natively. Also, you can simplify `arr[$i]=$(( ${arr[$i]} + 1 ))` to `arr[$i]++`

Comment: I do not know about your preferred languages, but e.g. FORTRAN does support `arr(:) = arr(:) + 1` or `arr3(:) = arr1(:) * arr2(:)` , so I had the hope that BASH would be capable. Sorry, I cannot reproduce the `arr[$i]++` thing. Care to explain?

Comment: forgot the parenthesis. correct syntax is `(( $arr[$i]++ ))`

Comment: The shell would only be looping in the background anyway if there were a function. So if it bothers you just write your own function to do it.

Comment: @Plutox sorry, still cannot reproduce, could you explicitly write the for loop start to end? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @User112638726 Not a matter of speed, just in terms of readability and being nosy how far BASH arithmetics could take me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know your question is not fresh new but you can accomplish what you want by declaring your array as `integer` and then applying a substitution:

```
declare -ia arr=( 1 2 3 )
value=1

declare -ia 'arr_added=( "${arr[@]/%/+$value}" )'
echo "arr_added: ${arr_added[*]}"

value=42
declare -ia 'arr_added=( "${arr[@]/%/+$value}" )'
echo "arr_added: ${arr_added[*]}"
```

It outputs:

```
arr_added: 2 3 4
arr_added: 43 44 45
```

You can perform other math operations as well:

```
value=3
declare -ia 'arr_multd=( "${arr[@]/%/*$value}" )'
echo "arr_multd: ${arr_multd[*]}"
```

Outputs:

```
arr_multd: 3 6 9
```

Comment: Thank you - in my tests also works without using quotes, e.gg `declare -ia new_arr=( ${arr[@]}/%/+$value }`. Is there any documentation regarding this? I didn't see it in `man bash`.

Comment: Yes, there is no direct mention for `-i` in array documentation neither in any man page nor TLDP or the like. You can check `-i`, though in "Typing variables: declare or typeset" [http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html]. It works for any variable, including arrays.

Answer (score -1):

you can use eval to have the feeling of lambda function (not sure about the syntax but this should be the main idea ) :

```
eval "function add1 { x=$1; y=$((x+1)) ; return $y; }"
for (( i=0 ; i<=${#arr[@]}-1 ; i++ )) ; do
    add1 ${arr[i]}
done
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. OP wants to avoid a for loop altogether

Comment: It also is a pointless use of `eval`, since the parameter expansions will be expanded before the function is ever defined.  `return` is used to return an exit status, not a computation.