# Multiply all values in txt file in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file that I need to multiply each number with -1. I have tried some commands but the result I get every time is only the first column multiplied with -1. Please help!

The file is as follows:

```
-1 2 3 -4 5 -6
7 -8 9 10 12 0
```

The expected output would be

```
1 -2 -3 4 -5 6
-7 8 -9 -10 -12 0
```

Commands I have tried are:

```
awk '{print $0*-1}' file
sed 's/$/ -1*p /' file  | bc (syntax error)
sed 's/$/ * -1 /' file  | bc (syntax error)
numfmt --from-unit=-1 < file (error: numfmt: invalid unit size: ‘-1’)
```

Answer (score 6):

With bash and an array:

```
while read -r -a arr; do
  declare -ia 'arr_multiplied=( "${arr[@]/%/*-1}" )';
  echo "${arr_multiplied[*]}";
done < file
```

Output:

```
1 -2 -3 4 -5 6
-7 8 -9 -10 -12 0
```

I got this idea from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46242196/3776858) by [j4x](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466339/j4x).

Comment: That's a neat trick. Had no idea you can use integer attributes with arrays.

Comment: @Shawn: I still had in mind that it is possible to apply an operation to all elements of an array. [j4x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46242196/3776858) had the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

One `awk` approach:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i*-1} 1' file
1 -2 -3 4 -5 6
-7 8 -9 -10 -12 0
```

Using the `<var_or_field><op>=<value>` construct:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i*=-1} 1' file
1 -2 -3 4 -5 6
-7 8 -9 -10 -12 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using perl and its [autosplit mode](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-a):

```bash
perl -lane 'print join(" ", map { $_ * -1 } @F)' file
```

Answer (score 1):

To multiply every number in the file with -1, you can use the following '**awk**'command:

```
   `awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i=$i*-1; print }' file`
```

This command reads each line of the file, and for each field (number) in the line, it multiplies it by -1. It then prints the modified line.

The output will be as follows:

```
    1 -2 -3 4 -5 6
    -7 8 -9 -10 -12 0
```

Alternatively, you can use the following '**sed**' command:

```
   sed 's/-\([0-9]*\)/\1/g; s/\([0-9]*\)/-\1/g' file
```

This command replaces all negative numbers with their positive equivalent, and all positive numbers with their negative equivalent. The output will be the same as above.

Comment: Did you test the `sed`? These substitutions both happen sequentially on each line, so it will make all fields positive and then negative before printing.

Comment: I create quickly, some editing may be required.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness an approach with ruby.

- **-l** Line-ending processing
- **-a** Auto-splitting, provides $F (field, set with -F)
- **-p** Auto-prints $_ (line)
- **-e** Execute code

```
ruby -lape '$_ = $F.map {|x| x.to_i * -1}.join " "' file
1 -2 -3 4 -5 6
-7 8 -9 -10 -12 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just switching the signs ought to do.

```
$: cat file
1 -2 -3 4 -5 6
-7 8 -9 -10 -12 0

$: sed 's/^ */ /; s/  */  /g; s/  -/ /g; s/  / -/g; s/-0/0/g; s/^ *//;' file
-1 2 3 -4 5 -6
7 -8 9 10 12 0
```

If you don't care about leading spaces or signs on your zeros, you can drop some of that. The logic is flexible, too...

```
$: sed 's/ *-/+/g; s/ / -/g; s/+/ /g;' x
1 2 3 -4 5 -6
 7 -8 9 10 12 -0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways we can do this.
I can think of the following 2 ways

```
cat file | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){ $i*=-1} print}'
```

This will give out

```
1 -2 -3 4 -5 6
-7 8 -9 -10 -12 0
```

In this method we overwrite the $i value and print $0

**Another way**

```
cat random.xml | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf("%d ",$i*-1)} printf("\n")  }'
```

Gives the output

```
1 -2 -3 4 -5 6
-7 8 -9 -10 -12 0
```

In this method we print the value $i*-1 and so we need to use printf() function

Answer (score 0):

don't "do math" and actually multiply by `-1` -

just use `regex` to flip the signs, and process thousands or even millions of numbers with 3 calls to `gsub()`